# UTF-8 decoding an ANSI encoded file throws an error

Tags: python, utf-8

Here's something I'm trying to understand. I was under the impression that UTF-8 was backwards compatible, so that I can *always* decode a text file with UTF-8, even if it's an ANSI file. But that doesn't seem to be the case:

```py
In [1]: ansi_str = 'éµaØc'

In [2]: with open('test.txt', 'w', encoding='ansi') as f:
   ...:     f.write(ansi_str)
   ...:

In [3]: with open('test.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
   ...:     print(f.read())
   ...:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-b0711b7b947e> in <module>
      1 with open('test.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
----> 2     print(f.read())
      3

c:\program files\python37\lib\codecs.py in decode(self, input, final)
    320         # decode input (taking the buffer into account)
    321         data = self.buffer + input
--> 322         (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
    323         # keep undecoded input until the next call
    324         self.buffer = data[consumed:]

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-1: invalid continuation byte
```

So it looks like if my code expects UTF-8, and is likely to encounter an ANSI-encoded file, I need to handle the UnicodeDecodeError. That's fine, but I would appreciate if anyone could throw some light on my initial misunderstanding.

Thanks!

Comment: When you say "likely to encounter an ANSI-encoded file", do you mean that the reader's system's user's current default character set at the time of reading will be the same as the writer's system's user's default character set at the time of writing?

Comment: I just mean that the file is a CSV file passed as a parameter, and I have to account for the possibility that the user is passing an ANSI-encoded file.

Comment: You either have to tell them which character encoding to use or let them tell you which they did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UTF-8 is backwards compatible with ***ASCII***. Not ANSI. "ANSI" doesn't even [describe any one particular encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_character_set). And those characters you're testing with are well outside the ASCII range, so unless you actually encode them with UTF-8, you can't read them as UTF-8.

Comment: OK, thanks. I guess that the fact that 'ansi' is a valid encoding value in Python played a role in my confusion.